# How to get field from object where predicate in find() is inside of subObject

Tags: scala

I have data structure similar to following:

```
case class Documents(
reference: String,
amount: BigDecimal,
date: LocalDate,
transactions: Seq[Transactions]
)

case class Transactions(
key: String,
date: LocalDate,
secret: String
)
```

Now I would like to find a reference from `Seq[Document]` where a key in sequence of Transaction objects matches some specific key.

When I try something like this :

```
documents.flatMap(_.transactions).find(_.key == argumentPassed)
```

I get Transaction object and I would like Document object, or reference from that object

Comment: is `documents` a `Seq[Documents]`? it confuses me because it has the same name of the case class. Is that is the case, doing `documents.flatMap(_.transactions)` you get a `Seq[Transactions]`.

Comment: How about: `documents.find(_.transactions.exists(_.key == argumentPassed))` +1 for naming your classes in singular

Comment: @Lesiak Thank you, your answer is solution. Classes are named properly in code, sorry, this was just dummy example, but good catch ! :)

Answer (score 3):

doing

```scala
documents.flatMap(_.transactions)
```

The return type of that, is a `Seq[Transactions]`. Which means, you loose the `Documents`. Maybe adding a field that have a reference to the `Document` that contain the `Transaction` could solve the problem. Doing the `find` over that result will return a transaction and you could get the `Document` you want.

The other approach could be

```scala
val documents: Seq[Documents] = Seq(...)
documents
  .find(doc => doc.transactions.exists(t => "key"))
```

So, applying the `find` over the `Seq[Documents]` will return a `Option[Documents]`. Inside the find method, you can look for the transaction you want just to check if the it is there using the method `exists`.

---

I suggest to name the classes using singular nouns. `Document` instead of `Documents`. Same for transaction. Doing that, will avoid confusions. Unless the class represents a collection of something, the name should be singular

Answer (score 1):

Pick your favourite:

```scala
val doc1 = documents.find(_.transactions.exists(_.key == argumentPassed))
val doc2 = documents.find(_.transactions.view.map(_.key).contains(argumentPassed))
val doc3 = documents.find(_.transactions.map(_.key).contains(argumentPassed))
```

The first one is likely to create the smallest amount of temporary objects - I would pick that one.